# Scaffolding Components with Insertable Placeholders in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am trying to create a Sitecore site with a main Layout called _Main.  The _Main layout has one Placeholder called Content.

I want to allow the author to insert components (Renderings, I guess) into this Placeholder.  The components he will be allowed to insert will have names like...

- Two_Column_Right
- Two_Column_Left
- One_Column

These are basically "scaffolding" components which, in turn, will have their own internal placeholders (e.g. RightRail, LeftRail, Center).  The author will then be able to insert “real” components into these placeholders.

The goal is to allow the user to dynamically build the layout of the page.

My question is this:  Will this work. Has anyone done it before?  Will I need to use dynamic placeholders? Will this be possible using the Experience Editor?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "Primarily Opinion Based", although a valid question it would be better asked on [Sitecore Community Forums](https://community.sitecore.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common pattern of 'containers' which should definitely leverage dynamic placeholders. Otherwise, you will get into issues if you have two one-columns on a page and need to have a user add it to the correct one-column container.

So, so to your questions:

1. Yes it will work.
2. You should use dynamic placeholders or you will be severely limiting yourself and causing editors issues.
3. This can be done in Experience Editor, it is just a normal rendering after all.

Comment: Is there a specific DynamicPlaceholders implementation that may work best?

Comment: I honestly can't be objective on this, as I am part of the architecture team behind the Keystone accelerator. What I can say is that our dynamic placeholder implementation works for us. I would probably ask to have somebody neutral provide feedback here on the various implementations.